# StructureMap: How to register System.Type implementation

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I want to be able to register an implementation by specifying a `System.Type`. Here's how I can do it using Castle Windsor:

```
            var type = typeof(MessageQueueProcessorImpl); // configurable
            container.Register(
                Component.For<MessageQueueProcessorBase>()
                         .ImplementedBy(type)
```

I've tried the obvious with StructureMap:

```
            var type = typeof(MessageQueueProcessorImpl); // configurable
            For<MessageQueueProcessorBase>()
                .Use(type) // <-- not accepted
```

Is this possible with StructureMap (2.6.4.1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `Use` and `For` the same way - either the generic versions or the versions that take a type parameter.

```cs
IContainer container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For(typeof(MessageQueueProcessorBase))
     .Use(typeof(MessageQueueProcessorImpl));
});
```

or

```cs
IContainer container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For<MessageQueueProcessorBase>()
     .Use<MessageQueueProcessorImpl>();
});
```

Comment: That's so obvious when I look at it. Thanks for the quick response!